# Why ball fall at same location from where we throw it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, earth, relative-motion

I have a silly question. As we all know earth is rotates at a speed of 460 m per sec. So if I  throw a ball in the air for 10 sec than the ball must fall 4600 m away from me but these does not happen in real life. Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137191/207455

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Earth is spinning, so why don't we jump and land on a different location?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137191/)

Answer (score 1):

The ball shares your motion, and so does the air around you. For practical puposes, you are at rest, though at the equator you would be whizzing around at 1,000 mph. If the atmosphere did not fully share your motion, an enormous gust of wind would whisk your ball away, but it doesn't, unless it happens to be a very windy day.

Comment: Commas require a space after them, so it would be good if you edited your answer.

Comment: I don't think this answer is complete. Iif we were somehow tethered to the rotating earth by some other means other than gravity, and then we let go of the (now untethered) ball, the ball would not stay with us, even though it was with us initially. In other words, the ball, air, etc. moving with us initially is not a sufficient condition for the ball to remain with us at subsequent times. Other things must come into play as well.