# I were to travel to the other side of the world then is this logic possible? If no, why?

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity, space

I go straight up and stay stationary at a particular point (at a point above action of gravity) in the sky. The earth will rotate and I decide to drop down when my destination has come exactly below me. I would like to know why this is not possible and would like scientific justification.

Comment: You mean, like in Donald Duck cartoons. :P

Comment: Of course that's possible. But how would you manage to become stationary?

Comment: You mean you first stop your motion with the Earth rotation. Then you dont have to climb up, you only need to get back to Earth rotation somehow at proper moment.

Comment: Why can't we hover at a point above which the air moves with the earth? Is that above the action of gravity?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/58154/2451

Comment: I'm not sure what you have in mind by "at a point above action of gravity".  Be aware that neither the atmosphere, the space station or the Moon are 'above' the action of gravity.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can stay stationary, you will move 180 degrees in longitude.  Unless you started at the equator, you won't be at the opposite side of the world.  For example, if you start at San Francisco, CA (37.788 N, 122.466 W)  You would be at 37.788N, 57.534E, in Northern Iran near Turkmenistan.

Why can't you stay stationary?  You need somehow to overcome gravity.  If you use a helicopter or balloon, you will stay stationary *relative to the air* and rotate essentially with the earth.  You won't be able to let the earth rotate below you.  You also have to say stationary in what reference frame.  You need to be stationary *relative to a frame based on the center of the earth* that is oriented relative to the stars.  Otherwise the earth's orbital motion will cause you trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You can not become stationary. what ever you do, you are moving **with** the earth as it rotates.

(I think no more explanation is needed.)

Comment: Why can't we hover at a point above which the air moves with the earth? Is that above the action of gravity?

Comment: @AmitAmola what do you mean above the "action of the gravity" ?

Comment: And what if you do it above the pole? You get nowhere, but remain stationary...

Comment: @jaromrax you mean you'll float on the air and don't fall down? I think I'm not getting you guys, are you trolling?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would work. The trouble is becoming stationary. The earth is moving, and the trees, sky, and even you are moving with it.