# What will happen if a helicopter flew still?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, atmospheric-science, relative-motion

I discussed this question with some of my friends. I was given many solutions. Please provide me the exact solution for this problem.

If a helicopter flew still in the same position for some hours, will its position change over time due to the rotation of the earth?.

One discussion referred that, since both earth and helicopter are in the same frame of reference, the helicopter always flew in the same position.

Another one told that the helicopter would move.

Please explain me the exact solution.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/58154/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1193/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The helicopter will stand still with respect to the atmosphere and the atmosphere rotates wtih the same speed as the earth, so with respect to earth the helicopter would also stand still.  If you search for "Sheikh Bandar al-Khaibari" you will find a "proof" why the earth does not rotate based on the Gedankenexperiment of a helicopter standing still....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the atmosphere rotate along with the earth?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1193/)

Answer (score 3):

Depends on how you define

> If a helicopter flew still in a same position

1. Same position relative to its surroundings? If it hovers above its platform it will not move relative to the platform, but it will travel some distance relative to the sun, and some other distance relative to the centre of the galaxy, and so on.
2. Same position relative to something else? Again it will travel some distance relative some other frame of reference

This means that no matter how fast **you think** you're going or how still **you think** you're standing, if the frame of reference is chosen wisely you will be wrong. (unless you're traveling at relativistic speeds, than its a different discussion)

Answer (score 0):

No the helicopter stays at rest w.r.t to the atmosphere. The atmosphere moves and so does the helicopter with it. Had the atmosphere not been at rest we shall be facing winds above a thousand km/hr which we don't . So we know what's the correct answer !