# Vertically move in a helicopter to go somewhere on Earth

Tags: velocity, earth, relative-motion

Is it possible to go from point A to point B (which are on same latitude) by hovering above A and wait till the earth rotates to point B below and then come down vertically?

I believe there would be some more subtleties involved which I could not think of.

Comment: We don't see birds zooming westward at 1,000 miles per hour as the earth rotates under them, and we don't experience a 1,000 mile per hour wind, because the air moves with the rotating earth.

Comment: @S. McGrew can you please elaborate?

Comment: Please read the answers given in [https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1193/why-does-the-atmosphere-rotate-along-with-the-earth] and [https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/58154/can-a-hovering-helicopter-travel-half-the-globe-in-12-hours].