# If I levitate at the same place will I come back to the same place after Earth taking it's one complete revolution?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, time, earth, levitation

so i have this question if i mean if we can levitate and decide to levitate and not stay on ground but at a place to look the ground, and we that earth rotates right and we rotate along with it cause we stick to it. But if we levitate and and on the ground can we see the place below us rotating and if yes, if we stay there for the next 24 hours will we return back to the same place?
ahhh just asking!

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/58154/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1193/2451 and links therein.

Comment: "Levitate" does not have any specific technical meaning. If a body is levitated, that probably means its weight is supported by something other than direct mechanical contact, but that's _all_ it means. It doesn't imply anything about forces acting (or not acting) horizontally on the body.