# Green Aurora Light: Experimental Replication?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, electricity, plasma-physics, electrochemistry

From what I've read, the green light found in the earth's auroras is the result of a reaction between oxygen and nitrogen (supposedly a new element was once proposed to explain it until the science was better understood). This happens, apparently, when electrons / and/or plasma are accelerated by the planet's magnetic fields. This color of plasma is somewhat unusual given the dominant gasses.

So, does anyone know how to replicate this phenomena experimentally, i.e., an official experiment or a non-official manner in which it happens during some other process? Also, more info on the physics / chemistry would be nice too!

As far as I can see, there is little info on replicating this phenomena, so help would be great. thanks.

For reference, here is a typical oxygen plasma, which is easy to create:

[image]

Comment: Related:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/382414/59023

Comment: @honeste_vivere thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Aurora light's physics is related to Alfven waves: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfv%C3%A9n_wave , which are observed in experiments on magneto-hydrodynamics. Hope this helps somehow.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time!