# Aurora Borealis

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, atmospheric-science, plasma-physics, solar-wind

As we know that during a solar flare, a large number of electrons and protons are ejected from the sun.
Some of them get trapped in the earth’s magnetic field and move in helical paths along the
field lines. The field lines come closer to each other near the magnetic poles.
Hence the density of charges increases near the poles. These particles collide with atoms
and molecules of the atmosphere. Excited oxygen atoms emit green light and excited
nitrogen atoms emit pink light.

So is it possible to (or a device already exists of which I am unaware) concentrate the magnetic fields of the earth say near your house for enjoying the view? (if you know what I mean) Or can we depict the MEC in any other form on such a large scale?

Comment: Somewhat related:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/382414/59023

Answer (score 0):

> So is it possible to (or a device already exists of which I am unaware) concentrate the magnetic fields of the earth say near your house for enjoying the view?

In general, no.  In principle, yes.  The [magnetic moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_moment) of the Earth's [magnetic field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetosphere) is huge.  While we can generate large magnetic fields for short periods of time (e.g., pulsed electromagnets), it's extremely difficult and energetically restrictive/expensive to generate a sustained magnetic moment of such large magnitude (not even sure it's possible, actually).

> Or can we depict the MEC in any other form on such a large scale?

I am not sure as I do not know to what MEC refers.

> These particles collide with atoms and molecules of the atmosphere. Excited oxygen atoms emit green light and excited nitrogen atoms emit pink light.

As I note in this answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/382414/59023, this is not quite correct.  There are multiple excitation emission lines from diatomic and monatomic nitrogen and oxygen.