# Why is the color of aurora borealis the way it is?

Tags: electrostatics, electromagnetic-radiation, atmospheric-science

Why is aurora borealis mostly green,  instead of pink,  even though green light is emitted by excited oxygen atoms and pink light by excited nitrogen atoms? As nitrogen is present almost more than three times the oxygen in the atmosphere, shouldn't it be more pink? 
Please correct me if I'm misinformed about it being mostly green. 
I personally feel that maybe oxygen componds are more in the regions(say, the ozone layer part of the stratosphere?) where the aurora borealis actually occurs, so maybe we need to see the composition of air in that region?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=aurora+borealis&client=firefox-b-ab&sa=N&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&ved=0ahUKEwiRqJy63MHbAhXsLMAKHVF3AuU4ChDsCQg-&biw=1366&bih=654  . it is complicated see this https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0016003228907917  also this https://www.windows2universe.org/earth/Magnetosphere/tour/tour_earth_magnetosphere_09.html&lang=sp

Comment: Related:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/382414/59023 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/335325/59023