# Why is aurora borealis circular in shape when viewed from space?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, earth, plasma-physics, geomagnetism, solar-wind

These are some false color images of the northern lights captured by NASA's satellite *Dynamics Explorer-1*.

[image]

*Image credits: [Dynamics Explorer - 1 (DE-1)
Spin-Scan Auroral Imaging (SAI)
Photo Gallery](http://www-pi.physics.uiowa.edu/sai/gallery/)*

It's interesting that what we see as longitudinal bands from Earth are part of larger rings when viewed from space. I thought that the aurora is formed when charged particles from the sun ionize the earth's atmosphere. I cannot understand why that can happen only in this circular ring. Are there any simple explanations for this phenomenon?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the field is stronger at the north pole, but it also has very little surface area perpendicular to the sun.  The majority of the north pole field lines perpendicular to the sun are looped around in the other direction far away from the earth where the field density is much lower.

Consider electrons traveling toward the earth with only one velocity. As they get closer to the earth the magnetic field gets stronger.  Eventually the electrons will spin around the field lines of sufficient strength *and* travel ***along*** *just* that field line.  Since that field line intersects the surface of the earth at just one geomagnetic latitude, the electrons will only interact at that latitude forming a band.

In the below picture, the field density is eventually strong enough to deflect the particles along the field lines. Before that point, it is interacting with the field lines from the magnetic north pole.

[image: Solar wind interacting with Earth's magnetic field]

Now the electrons do not immediately interact with the atmosphere, but they instead get reflected back and forth between the poles and drift eastward (west for positive ions) while doing so, causing the night sky to be illuminated just as well as the day side when the electrons eventually interact with the atmosphere.

That should explain why the aurora is not as prevalent at the north pole and why it is visible as a ring around the day and night side.

Comment: I am not sure from where you got this image, but the northern (geographic) auroral oval is mostly on the night-side of Earth and most of the electrons generating it come from the geomagetic tail.

Answer (score 9):

Only some of the aurora patterns are circular; most of them are more irregular and blobby in shape.

It is known that the aurora itself is created when electrons in the earth's geomagnetic tail and high-speed electrons and protons (called the *solar wind*) shot into space by the sun interact with the earth's magnetic field in space (called the *magnetosphere*).

Those particles have their trajectories bent by the magnetic field as they penetrate it. The amount of bend depends on a bunch of stuff but mostly by how fast they are moving and what the shape and extent of the magnetosphere happens to be (which itself changes from day to day).

If most of the particles in the wind have approximately the same energy, then they will get bent in the same amount which tends to focus and accelerate a cloud of incoming particles into a ring as they approach the earth.

Comment: That makes sense. One more question. The electrons are sort of guided by the magnetic field lines of Earth, correct? So the place where magnetic field lines are most intense should have a higher density of electron clouds. If you consider Earth to be a bar magnet (which is a questionable assumption), aren't the magnetic field lines closest at the poles? So, shouldn't you expect a *disc* of aurora, instead of a ring on the poles?

Comment: @AlphaLife It seems like you might be expecting electrons to be "attracted" to areas of higher field strength, but that's not how electromagnetism works. The Lorentz force on a charged particle in a magnetic field acts *at right angles* to the particle's motion, causing it to move in a helical trajectory *around* the field lines (see e.g. https://www.swpc.noaa.gov/sites/default/files/images/u33/Chapter_4.pdf)

Comment: @David No, I am aware of that, but thanks for the pdf.  That's precisely what I meant when I said elections are 'guided' by the field lines. The density of field lines is more near the poles of a magnet, so a higher flux of electrons would be guided toward the poles. The question is why then, you don't see aurora in the entirety of the poles but only as a ring

Comment: the disc width depends on the energy distribution in the solar wind. if all the particles have about the same energy, then you get a ring. see the wikipedia article.

Comment: Quick note:  Most of the electrons that generate the aurora (most terrestrial aurora is due to electrons) come from the geomagnetic tail, not directly from the solar wind...

Comment: @honeste_vivere, will edit. -NN

Answer (score 4):

> Why is aurora borealis circular in shape when viewed from space?

The [aurora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurora) emissions you see are not actually circular, but rather oval shaped.  They can look somewhat circular but they usually distend toward the nightside (i.e., anti-sunward side) because the Earth's [magnetosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetosphere) is stretched on the nightside (forming the *geomagnetic tail* or *magnetotail*).  The tail forms due to the asymmetry in the [solar wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_wind) dynamic pressure.  In fact, most of the electrons that generate the aurora come directly from the magnetotail, not the solar wind.

> I thought that the aurora is formed when charged particles from the sun ionize the earth's atmosphere.

I wrote two other detailed answers at https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/382414/59023 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/335325/59023.  The basic idea here is that electrons with kinetic energies in the ~1-10 keV range strike neutral oxygen or nitrogen and excite their orbital electrons which then emit photons during the de-excitation of the excited electron.  The characteristic bright green you see is from oxygen.

Unfortunately, many of the popular science articles get the source wrong.  They often say that charged particles from the Sun hit the upper atmosphere.  Most of the particles come from the geomagnetic tail, not directly from the solar wind.  They are accelerated toward Earth by processes like [magnetic reconnection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_reconnection) and wave-particle interactions with electromagnetic fluctuations like [Alfven waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfv%C3%A9n_wave) and [whistler waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whistler_(radio)).

Why the aurora focus around the geomagnetic poles is also confused in these popsci articles.  The has to due to [mirror forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_mirror) acting on charged particles orbiting a magnetic field and moving along it.  The more detailed explanation involves so called *adiabatic invariants* of charged particle motion (e.g., see answer at https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/670591/59023).  The basic premise is that the dominant magnetic field geometry of Earth, close to the surface, is that of a giant dipole (it's tiltled off from the geographic poles by ~11 degrees).  To move toward the Earth near the equator would require particles to move across the magnetic field.  It is possible to do this, but the [Lorentz force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force) tends to make this very difficult.  The only places where the magnetic field points towards the Earth's surface are near the geomagnetic poles (Note that magnetic north is near the south geographic pole).  So the one place where particles can move roughly along the magnetic field toward the surface are near the geomagnetic poles.

> I cannot understand why that can happen only in this circular ring.

It's not actually circular.  It's more oval-shaped or oblate than circular, most of the time.  It distends into the nightside more than the dayside due to the stretching/compression of the geomagnetic field.

> Are there any simple explanations for this phenomenon?

The distortion of the nominal dipole magnetic topology due to the solar wind and other magnetic anomalies tends to make the magnetic poles distorted toward the nightside (i.e., away from the solar wind) more than not.  This results in the oval shape.  It can become more circular during "quiet times."